# Words with repeated letters in Bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, command-line

```
egrep \e '(a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z){2,}' dict.txt
```

What am I doing wrong? The dictionary words are all in lower-case letters.

In case the interval feature `{}` was not supported by `egrep`, which command should I use?

Comment: Is this what you want? [`([a-z])\1`](http://regex101.com/r/yY4uM2/1)

Comment: I didn't know you could reference a match in the same expression. It worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yup, no problem! Here's some more information on [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html).

Comment: Options in Linux use `-`, not backslashes: `egrep -e` in place of `egrep \e`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do simply like this,

```
egrep -e '([a-z])\1+' file
```

Example:

```
$ cat file
bbar 
fooohsg
jhfd
$ egrep -e '([a-z])\1+' file
bbar 
fooohsg
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape the  `{}`

`grep '\([a-z]\)\1\{1,\}' dict.txt` will match any number of repeatitions

```
$ echo "aab" | grep '\([a-z]\)\1\{1,\}'
aab
```

Comment: **who said it would match the repeated characters?** Run this command `echo "abc" | grep '[a-z]\{2,\}'`